# PhoneGapBuild - download sqlite db and connect to it

Tags: javascript, android, iphone, sqlite, phonegap-build

Been banging my head against this wall for a while so hoping the hive mind can help me out.

I am trying to download and attach a sqlite database ('database.db') from a remote location and although I can download it fine, I am struggling to connect to it using window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({  name : databaseName  });

Any ideas or has anyone ever been able to download and attach a sqlite db in phonegapbuild?

```
var _urlContactsSqlite = 'https://www.dropbox.com/s/370lyi2w21pxgrs/database.db?dl=1';



function init() {
        var databaseName = 'database.db';
        window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, 
            function requestFileSystemSuccess(fs) {             //fs = filesystem
                console.log('requestFileSystemSuccess');
                fs.root.getDirectory('databases', { create: true },         //create the directory if it doesnt exist
                    function getDirectorySuccess(dataEntry) {
                        console.log('getDirectorySuccess');
                        fs.root.getFile('dummy.html', {create: true, exclusive: false}, 
                            function getFileSuccess(fileEntry) {
                                console.log('getFileSuccess');
                                var sPath = fileEntry.nativeURL.replace('dummy.html','') + 'databases/';
                                console.log('sPath: ' + sPath);
                                var ft = new FileTransfer();
                                ft.download(
                                    encodeURI(_urlContactsSqlite),
                                    sPath + databaseName, 
                                    function downloadSuccess(entry) {
                                      console.log('downloadSuccess - what now smarty pants');
                                      console.log('now we have the database in a location, we should try and open it.');
                                      $rootScope._db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({
                                                name : databaseName
                                      });
                                        console.log('attempting to get a count of the contacts table');
                                        var promise = dbQuery.contacts_Count();
                                        promise
                                            .then(function(data) {
                                                console.log(data);
                                                alert(data);    
                                            })
                                            .catch(function(error) {
                                                console.log('error occurred inside promise : ' + error );
                                            });
                                    }, 
                                    function downloadFail(e) {
                                        console.log('downloadFail', e);
                                        console.log('error source ' + e.source);
                                        console.log('error target ' + e.target);
                                        console.log('error code ' + e.code);
                                    }, 
                                  false, null); //end fileTransfer                                  
                            },
                            function getFileFail(e) {
                                console.log('getFileFail',e);
                            }
                        );
                    }, 
                    function getDirectoryFail(e) 
                    {
                        console.log('getDirectoryFail',e);
                    }
                  );        //end requestFileSystem
            },
            function requestFileSystemFail(){
                console.log('requestFileSystemFail');
            }
        );  //end requestFileSystem
    }   // end init()
```

dbQuery.contacts_Count();

```
function contacts_Count() {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            setTimeout(function() {
                    $rootScope._db.transaction(function(tx) {
                            var sql = 'SELECT COUNT(*) AS COUNT FROM contacts;';
                            console.log(sql);
                            tx.executeSql(sql, [], function(tx, results) {
                                    var rowCount = results.rows.item(0).COUNT;
                                    console.log('rowcount: ' + rowCount);
                                    deferred.resolve(rowCount);
                            }, null);
                    });

            },1);
            return deferred.promise;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing this is due to where SqlitePlugin is looking for your database. It appears in your code that you're downloading it to a Databases directory, whereas the plugin only looks in the www subdirectory. Per the [documentation](https://github.com/brodysoft/Cordova-SQLitePlugin#pre-populated-database) for Pre-populated databases:

> For Android & iOS (only): put the database file in the www directory and open the database like:

```
var db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name: "my.db", createFromLocation: 1});
```

---- Edit below:

Consider adding some error checking in your `_db.transaction` function, as so:

```
$rootScope._db.transaction(function(tx) {
        var sql = 'SELECT COUNT(*) AS COUNT FROM contacts;';
        console.log(sql);
        tx.executeSql(sql, [], function(tx, results) {
                var rowCount = results.rows.item(0).COUNT;
                console.log('rowcount: ' + rowCount);
                deferred.resolve(rowCount);
        }, null);
    },
    function(error) {
        console.log('db error: ' + error.message);
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Mike :)

I removed the databases reference and used the above example with the createFromLocation parameter. 

The console log is as below but still no dice?
`code`
sPath: file:///data/data/my.app.reverse.url/files/files/ 
downloadSuccess
now we have the database in a location, we should try and open it. 
SQLitePlugin openargs: {"name":"database.db","createFromLocation":1} 
attempting to get a count of the contacts table 
SELECT COUNT(*) AS COUNT FROM contacts;
.... nothing else
`code`
Thanks again!

Comment: I'd recommend editing your post to include what's in the dbQuery.contacts_Count function. Additionally, I do not think you're using promises correctly. We'll revisit that once you post what's in that function.

Comment: Not a problem. Your promises look fine. I've edited my answer. Definitely add some more error checking in the db handling itself.

Comment: The console returns "a statement with no error handler failed: no such table: contacts (code 1)". Seems that the database isnt being attached after all.

Comment: I'd recommend working on a simple proof of concept without downloading the database. Drop the database manually onto the phone, and try opening it. If it doesn't, try making sure it's in your project's `www` directory. Once you get that down, the rest should be pretty trivial for you. Good luck!